# How to add images in email with django allauth

Tags: python, django

I have troubles with django allauth
Here's my template

## password_reset_key_message.txt

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}Hello{% if username %}, {{ username }}{% endif %}!

{% if username %}{% blocktrans %}In case you forgot, your username is {{ username }}.{% endblocktrans %}{% endif %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you or someone else has requested a password for your user account.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.

{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "avatar.jpg" %}" alt="avatar" />

{{ password_reset_url }}

{% if username %}{% blocktrans %}In case you forgot, your username is {{ username }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% endif %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Thank you for using {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I'm trying to add image in email body (already trying with link on source and converting image to `base64`) but got same result

But when I click on reset_email I got this result:
[image]

Comment: did you add STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL to settings.py?

Comment: @Meryem template sanitazed all `HTML` tags. `<img src="{% static "https://image-url.png" %}" alt="avatar" />` not working also

Comment: @Meryem and yes I set STATIC_URL in settings.py

Comment: i guess you shouldn't use static in this case, try this way ```<img src="https://image-url.png" alt="avatar"> </img> ```also do not use self closing, use seperate close tag

Comment: @Meryem Thank you but it doesn't working too :)

Comment: hi sir have you solved this problem ?